# a staggerline of Trubies

Tags: meaning

In Nalo Hopkinson's short story "Ours is the Prettiest" (published in the collection *Falling in Love with Hominids*, 2015), I found the following sentence (emphasis mine):

> I swung aside the skeletal bustle that was the skirt of my gown just in time to get it out from underfoot of **a staggerline of Trubies**, everyone of them dressed to pussfoot in gleaming white canvas bell-bottoms, sailor shirts and beanies.

Earlier in the story, the narrator had said that the eyes of her companion Gladstone were "silver, from the Trubie side of her family", so "Trubie" is clearly a family name. However, I couldn't find "staggerline" in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=staggerline&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go), the [online Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english?q=staggerline), the [online Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=staggerline) (I have no access to the OED), the [online Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=staggerline) or with a more general [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=staggerline+definition&t=ffab&ia=web).

So what does "staggerline" mean?

Comment: Perhaps a typo, intended to be a ‘staggering line of Trubies’?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That possibility can't be excluded, even though I can't remember seeing other typos in Hopkinson's stories (at least in print).

Comment: Another possibility is that it was simply a nonce word that came to the author and is meant to bring associations of a staggering line of people. (A lack of typos in a printed book usually means good editors and proofreaders – but even good editors and proofreaders miss things. It sometimes happens that typesetters accidentally introduce new errors when fixing old ones, and not always in a place the editor thinks to reread if it’s late enough in the process.)

Answer (score 2):

The word is not listed in the OED, so I think it’s a portmanteau of *stagger* and *congaline*. Or just *line*.  The story has that type of a conversational tone, so I think it would fit. Given that this story was published in several different places this way it seems very unlikely it’s a typo.

Later on that page it does say that they were going in a line, careening, stumbling, and zigzagging. Or as the narrator describes it: “‘Truebloods playing Drunken Sailor mas’”.